Issues with top margin alignment and header spacing
I am currently working on a LaTeX document and I have encountered two distinct but maybe related problems.
I am new to LaTeX, and I've been learning it for about a week. I'm doing my best to solve the issues I encounter, but I'm not sure if the solutions I've found are the most appropriate, or if they are just "poor fixes."
Problem 1: Aligning part and chapter titles with top margin
I have noticed that aligning part and chapter title with top margin is quite challenging in LaTeX.
I used a trial-and-error method by adjusting empirically the vertical spacing between the titles, but the solution is somewhat imprecise.
EDIT: here is a full example of the code I used to align part, chapter, and ToC titles. Please find below the explanations of what I've tried.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, twoside]{report}

% --- Packages ---
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% --- Headers ---
\geometry{includehead}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\setlength{\headheight}{12pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{24pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\hspace{18pt}\nouppercase \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\thepage\hspace{18pt}\nouppercase \rightmark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

% --- Chapters page style ---
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhead[]{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
    \setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
}

% --- Part titles ---
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge}
    {\normalfont\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont\partname~\thepart}{6pt}            
    {\bfseries\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont}\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-17.5pt}{0pt}

% --- Chapter titles ---
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \normalfont\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont
        \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 6\p@
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
        #1
        \vphantom{gjpqybdhlt}
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 36\p@
    }}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \normalfont\bfseries\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont
        #1
        \vphantom{gjpqybdhlt}       
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 36\p@
    }}
\makeatother
    
% --- ToC title ---
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-13pt}
\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{36pt}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\bfseries\fontsize{30}{30}\selectfont}

\begin{document}    
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\part{Titre de la partie 1}
\chapter{Titre du chapitre 1}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}

For part titles, I empirically set the value at -17.5pt to align part titles with top margin, as well as with chapter titles. This value allows a seemingly perfect alignment. Similarly, I set the value at height -13pt for toc title to align it with part and chapter titles.
I am unsure why such different and seemingly "weird" values are needed for this. I suspect they may each have different default spacing values, which would explain why such manipulation are needed. I wonder if there is a more systematic approach to consistently align all the titles (part, chapter, and ToC) without adjusting each of their vertical spacing individually.
Note that I put \vphantom{gjpqybdhlt} in each chapter titles in order to avoid spacing discrepancies with the following text due to the presence or absence of ascending or descending letters in chapter titles. (This is unnecessary for part titles, as they appear on empty pages.) I wonder if there is a more simple way to get rid of this problem, but this works quite well for now.
Problem 2: Header spacing on chapter pages
The second issue concerns the headers, which I am handling with the \fancyhdr package.
I disabled the headers on pages that begin with a new chapter, but even though the header is empty, it still occupies space. This results in the chapter title being pushed down, and I want it to align with the top margin of the page.
EDIT: please refer to the example I gave at the beginning of the document to try my code.
Note that I included the header in the body of the document using \geometry{includehead}. I used \setlength{\headheight}{0pt} and \setlength{\headsep}{0pt} to try and solve the problem.
The chapter title aligns with the top margin, as expected. But, it seems that the entire body is shifting upwards, causing the bottom margin to be much larger than the top margin (I set all the margins at 1in via \geometry.)
Could you please help me address these issues in a cleaner and more efficient manner?
Thank you for your time and assistance.
Best,
Sam

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

You should not need to do this I put \vphantom{gjpqybdhlt} in each chapter titles in order to avoid spacing discrepancies with the following text due to the presence or absence of ascending or descending also if you do add such a strut do not add a spacebefore it, as it is you have a space before this so you could get a linbreak there leading to a spurious white second  line in the heading

Please also address the comments you've received on your earlier query.

Thank you @DavidCarlisle for your response.
Unfortunately, if I do not include \vphantom, the vertical spacing between a chapter's title and the following text varies depending on the presence of ascending or descending letters in the chapter's title, which causes vertical alignment differences from one chapter to another.
For example, the chapter titled "Conclusion" will have less vertical spacing than the chapter titled "Chapter 1" because of the presence of a descender letter.
Perhaps there is a simpler solution, but I haven't found one.

yes but tex line spacing should deal with that automatically so if that's not happening it's a sign of an error elsewhere but with no test file provided I havem't treaced

declarations such as \fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont are likely to introduce such problems as that is setting an impossibly tight baseline spacing, normally baseline is around 20% larger than the font size, eg 10pt font on 12pt spacing

if you use geometry, you shouldn't set \headheight or \headsep directly, but use geometry's interface. otherwise inconsistent spacing is expected. off-topic: do not load both lmodern or fontenc and fontspec. if you are using luatex, don't load lmodern or fontenc. if you are using pdftex, don't load fontspec. don't load inputenc either way.

@cfr thank you for your response, however I am not sure how to solve my problem using the geometry interface. Should I redefine margins for the chapter page style? If so, I don't know how to do this.

@DavidCarlisle thank you for the tip, but in my case it doesn't change anything, there still is vertical spacing discrepancies due to descending letters (unless I put my vphantom command).

the space before the vhantom (which should be \strut not guessing the letters you need) will affect you if you have a long enough title that that space falls at the end of the line. Also never use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} with luatex or xetex.

well, you are using a hodgepodge of competing approaches. it isn't really surprising you end up needing weird adjustments this way ;). and your goal is also a most unusual one. it is not at all standard to align everything at the top of the page this way, so not really something you'd expect to be supported out-of-the-box.

@DavidCarlisle when replacing the /vphantom by /strut the same problem occurs with descending letters. (Actually I didn't know that it could be an issue!)

@cfr I started learning LaTeX last sunday, so my approach is indeed quite approximative, that is why I need help haha. To be honest I don't know the standards for chapter's titles position. But you're probably right, I should quit the idea of aligning my titles with top margin.

to be honest, my best advice would be to work with as default a format as possible for at least your first couple of weeks ;). I wonder if you really know what your document will look like if you just use report. babel you need, definitely. and either fontenc for pdflatex or fontspec for lualatex/xelatex probably also. (definitely you need T1 if you use pdflatex as french won't typeset properly otherwise). the rest I would get rid of for now. concentrate on the body of the document and worry about the format later when you will have a better idea what changes you really want.

To be honest if you have been using latex for a week why are you adjusting the class layout in the way at all, that is not using latex it is modifying its code, quite a reasonable thing to do but not until you are familiar with its use.
